# Check array element that out of order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to get all the elements that out of order inside an array and push it to another array.

For example,

```
var arr=["2","3","7","4","5","6","1"];
```

7 and 1 is out of order, it there any possible way to get these elements that out of order?

Comment: Sure, but what code have you written?

Comment: first and second element is in order, so first element is always smaller than second. That's it ?

Comment: do you have a defined start value? what should happen, if your array is `[5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4]` is `[5, 6, 7, 8]` wrong or `[1, 2, 3, 4]`?

Comment: I would have an array defining the actual order [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],so the starting value should be 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with an object as `thisArg` for the next expected value.

```js
var arr = ["2", "3", "7", "4", "5", "6", "1"],
    notInOrder = arr.filter(function (a, i) {
        return i && this.next !== +a || (this.next = +a + 1, false);
    }, { next: null });

console.log(notInOrder);
```